# Retaining old loader after rotation in child activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have a problem with using old loader in new activity. 
**Situation** : I use AsyncTaskLoader in my application and call initLoader() in activity's onCreate() method to get some information from the internet, then I launch child activity,rotate device and press back button. After these actions initLoader() calls, but it does not get old loader, it creates a new one. 
**So I have following questiolns:**

1. When loader manager reattach old loaders to new activity?
2. How I can solve problem of retaining old loader?

P.S. When I rotate device without leaving activity, it's all ok.